# Example of overloading C++ extraction operator >> to parse data

Tags: c++, parsing, operator-overloading

I am looking for a good example of how to overload the stream input operator (operator>>) to parse some data with simple text formatting. I have read [this tutorial](http://bytes.com/topic/c/insights/652951-how-parse-file-c) but I would like to do something a bit more advanced. In my case I have fixed strings that I would like to check for (and ignore). Supposing the 2D point format from the link were more like

```
Point{0.3 =>
      0.4 }
```

where the intended effect is to parse out the numbers 0.3 and 0.4. (Yes, this is an awfully silly syntax, but it incorporates several ideas I need). Mostly I just want to see how to properly check for the presence of fixed strings, ignore whitespace, etc.

**Update:**
Oops, the comment I made below has no formatting (this is my first time using this site).
I found that whitespace can be skipped with something like

```
std::cin >> std::ws;
```

And for eating up strings I have

```
static bool match_string(std::istream &is, const char *str){
    size_t nstr = strlen(str);
    while(nstr){
        if(is.peek() == *str){
            is.ignore(1);
            ++str;
            --nstr;
        }else{
            is.setstate(is.rdstate() | std::ios_base::failbit);
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Now it would be nice to be able to get the position (line number) of a parsing error.

**Update 2:**
Got line numbers and comment parsing working, using just 1 character look-ahead. The final result can be seen here in [AArray.cpp](http://github.com/victorliu/AArray/tree/master), in the function parse(). The project is a (de)serializable C++ PHP-like array class.

Comment: It's not the "extraction" or "stream input" operator, it's the "bit shift" operator. The stream IO versions are themselves overloaded versions of the original C operator, which is relatively little used in practice.

Comment: Chris: While I don't disagree with you, it seems to be accepted practice to refer to the '>>' and '<<' operators independently as "stream input/output" operators. See Stroustrup's glossary definitions of << and >>: http://www.research.att.com/~bs/glossary.html

Comment: @GRB: Operator overloading isn't. The bitwise right shift operator has been abused by the c++ stl.
Consider operator ^. You could decide to use operator overloading to turn it into a raise-to-the-power operator. However, it simply has the wrong precedence and associativity. Given that novel new operators cannot be added, and the semantics of existing operators cannot be changed, AND the mechanic implicit in the terminology: "overloading", operator >> is the bitwise right shift operator, and everything else is understood as an overloaded form.

Comment: Chris B: Again, I don't disagree. That said, the overloading of '<<' and '>>' for streams is so ubiquitous that it is now acceptable to refer to them separately as stream 'operators'. My only point here is that we shouldn't be beating up on Victor for having used (apparently) accepted terminology; see my Stroustrup link.

Comment: I have put together a solution that skips whitespace with something like 'cin >> ws' and matching strings with code like

    static bool match_string(std::istream &is, const char *str){
        size_t nstr = strlen(str);
        while(nstr){
            if(is.peek() == *str){
                is.ignore(1);
                    ++str;
                    --nstr;
                }else{
                    is.setstate(is.rdstate() | std::ios_base::failbit);
                    return false;
                }
            }
        return true;
    }

Comment: Why don't you post your solution as an answer. You might get upvotes, and even earn the "self-educator" badge!

Answer (score 1):

Your operator>>(istream &, object &) should get data from the input stream, using its formatted and/or unformatted extraction functions, and put it into your object.

If you want to be more safe (after a fashion), construct and test an istream::sentry object before you start. If you encounter a syntax error, you may call `setstate( ios_base::failbit )` to prevent any other processing until you call my_stream.clear().

See `<istream>` (and istream.tcc if you're using SGI STL) for examples.